# Plone 4.2.4 shows incorrect local time/3.5 hours ahead

Tags: plone, zope

A fresh plone 4.2.4 install (Unified installer for Linux) writes wrong time for all Plone/Zope events.

My timezone is set to Asia/Jerusalem and the time is set to "local PC time".

Plone is ahead of it for exactly 3.5 (three and half) hours.

How can I fix this, and why this should happen at all?

System is OpenSuse 12.2

Comment: The DateTime implementation in Zope has some issues. What does `python -c import time; print time.tzname` give you? Most likely that value gives an ambiguous name (one that also is used in another timezone).

Comment: Maybe this post of David Blewett can help: http://www.sixfeetup.com/blog/zope-datetime-careful-with-that-dash-eugene

Comment: Hi if you are telling me to paste that code to the terminal then the first one gives me this:python -c import time
  File "<string>", line 1
    import
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @IdaEbkes: That is a completely different issue.

Comment: @MP: Apologies, I didn't include the quotes there, but I figured out what the return value would be in any case.

Comment: Could you clarify how to use that command , I don't know about the quotes since I am kind of a new-be to Linux and commands, but this command could be of use. ( by the way The "print" command doesn't seem to exist on my system at all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python can only give Zope the timezone as a three-letter abbreviation. For Asia/Jerusalem that is [`IST`](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/asia/ist-israel.html).

Unfortunately, that same abbreviation is also used for [India Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/asia/ist.html), which is exactly 3 and a half hours ahead of Asia/Jerusalem.

The solution is to add a `TZ` environment variable to your Zope buildout configuration, that *disambiguates* the timezone:

```
[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
...
environment-vars =
    TZ JIST-2JIDT-3,M3.5.5/2,M9.3.0/2
```

Here `JIST` is the Jerusalem IST versus other IST meanings, where current time is -2 UTC, and summertime moves to -3 UTC, on the last Friday in March at 2 o'clock, and moves to wintertime again on the 3rd Sunday in September, again at 2 o'clock.

Comment: I really thank you for this and just to make sure would like something for the future: when I move the ready site to the production server should I remove those lines ( I guess) from the buildout ? Unless the server is !! located in this time zone?

Comment: Exactly. The TZ variable fixes the timezone of the server.