# Plone: Set default timezone (for the entire website)

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

How to set timezone for my plone website?
I think there must be a global setting for this, but I can't find it.

Comment: I'm no longer cross posting your questions to our forum at https://community.plone.org I think you understand by now that you will get more people viewing and responding there than here.

Comment: No problem. It's perfect. I really like StackOverflow. If needed I will copy myself in community.plone.org my unanswered questions.

Comment: This seems to have been answered by Martijn Pieters in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983923/plone-4-2-4-shows-incorrect-local-time-3-5-hours-ahead Does that help you further?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plone 4.2.4 shows incorrect local time/3.5 hours ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983923/plone-4-2-4-shows-incorrect-local-time-3-5-hours-ahead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `plone.app.event` installed, you can set the default timezone for events under "Event Settings" (`/@@event-settings`).

Without `p.a.e`, there is, as far as I recall, no explicit support for timezones, so Plone will probably take the time zone globally configured for the server.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the TZ environment variable in your instance configuration (see the option 'environment-vars' in plone.recipe.zope2instance buildout recipe) setting your custom timezone.